# How hibernate provides repeatable reads

Tags: java, hibernate

I am going through the - [Chapter 13. Transactions and Concurrency](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch13.html) and came across below statement:

> Hibernate does not lock objects in memory. Your application can expect
>   the behavior as defined by the isolation level of your database
>   transactions. Through Session, which is also a transaction-scoped
>   cache, Hibernate provides repeatable reads for lookup by identifier
>   and entity queries and not reporting queries that return scalar
>   values.

I am not able to understand the statement: `Hibernate provides repeatable reads for lookup by identifier and entity queries and not reporting queries that return scalar values.`

- How Hibernate provides repeatable reads? Can someone please give me an example.
- What does it mean when the doc says `not reporting queries that return scalar values.`

Please help me in this.

Comment: It means that in single transaction (Hibernate) if you would fetch multiple times some entity (with the same PK) than it would be fetched from DB only for the first usage, later on, it would be returned from cache so the ammount of actual SQL performed are reduced.
As for the second point, I don't understand it neither.

Comment: Thanks for answering for my first question